# Algorithm for finding cheapest path when effect of adding a node is unknown

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I need to find the cheapest path between nodes `a` and `b` on a directed, weighted, cyclic graph, cheapest defined as eliciting the smallest return value from a given arbitrary `costfunc`. Normally Djikstra's would be the best choice I'd think, except `costfunc` takes an *entire path* - the effect of adding a single node is unknown (I suppose I could just run the `costfunc` with and without the given node and use the difference...).

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without some constraints on `costfunc` you can't do much better than trying every possible path. Suppose

```
costfunc = 1 / (sum of edge weights)
```

Then your problem (on cyclic graph) is NP hard [Longest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

And for

```
costfunc =
   sum of edge weights if path length = N
   infinity otherwise
```

you have well known NP complete [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: That's what I was worried about, yeah. Darn.